# How to make uiscrollview's paging page slower?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

Is it even possible to change the speed at which we page?  I know Apple does it with their iOS6 App Store.  But maybe they are using undocumented APIs.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an official way to change the paging speed, I don't know whether there are any private properties.

If you want to implement it yourself, you would have to implement the paging by responding to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods. However, you would also have to implement custom scrolling behaviour for a `UIScrollView`, as you cannot specify the duration of the animation of `setContentOffset:animated:`.

I have done something similar when I have tried to mimic the behaviour of the safari tab selection view. Perhaps some part of it helps you, solving your problem. First, I have implemented a [`UIScrollView` subclass](https://github.com/plancalculus/MOScrollView) whose `setContentOffset:animated:` takes a duration and a timing function. The [tab view](https://github.com/plancalculus/MOTabView) implements paging by using the delegate methods of `UIScrollView` and calling `setContentOffset:animated:` with a custom duration.